# How to use IF function to give out value in certain cell if a range equals particular cell (Sheet1!C:C=A1)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Function I am using:** `IF(Sheet!C:C=A1,Sheet!B:B,"False")`

**Probelm:** This returns false all the time.

**Scenario:**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Max |
| 2 | Cody |
| 3 | Jack |

In this sheet, I want that when I choose a number from 1-3, it should return the corresponding name in column B.

**Ideal Result of above formula:** Max

**Other formulas I have tried-**

`IF(Sheet!$C:$C=A1,Sheet!$B:$B,"False")`

`IF(Sheet!$C:$C=A:A,Sheet!$B:$B,"False")`

`ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Sheet!$C:$A=C:A,Sheet!$B:$B,"False")`

Answer (score 0):

you can try either:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(D2:D),IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D,A:B,2,)),))
```

OR

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(D2:D),XLOOKUP(D2:D,A:A,B:B,),))
```

- 

[image]